# Change style in Scout Eclipse Rap

Tags: css, disabled-control, eclipse-scout

I would like to change appearance of some element in rap scout project. I found folder with RAP.application.css file in it, but it is empty.

I would like to know how to use it, for fields disable color,...

Marko

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no single documentation page where you will find the information.

Here some inputs on the eclipse scout forum:

- [Scout Web App + CSS](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/367983/)
- [How to change theme on RAP client](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/629015/)
- [How to change theme (color)](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/488225/)