# Scout Eclipse button without backgroung image

Tags: button, background-image, eclipse-scout

I am looking how to get rid of background image of scout eclipse button. The default image is corner-rounded grey rectangle.

But I want button just with Label without background (image or color).

Marko

Comment: What UI-Technology are you using? For example, if you use Swing: scout creates a JButton. Style of this button is responibility of the Swing-LookAndFeel.

Comment: What if I want to set this for all, Swing and RAP?

Comment: There is no common code between the Swing LookAndFeel and the RAP Theme (2 different technologies).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you post answer for both technologies, pleas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some inputs how you can customize the theme / look and feel:

## RAP

You can use the RAP `css` or an other RAP theme.

See the question:
[Change style in Scout Eclipse Rap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117826/change-style-in-scout-eclipse-rap)

## Swing

Check how you can change the [Swing Look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html). Scout has some convenience functions to do this.

See: [How to customize the Rayo Look&Feel?](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/487608/1058999/#msg_1058999)

If you use [Rayo](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Rayo) (a skinnable Look And Feel based on [synth](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html)), there is a way to customize the XML.

## SWT

I am not sure to know what is possible to customize with this UI renderer.